# add a rewrite to firebase flutter web project to direct all calls to a cloud function

Tags: flutter, firebase-hosting, flutter-web

I have this firebase.json json:

```
 {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "headers": [
      { "source": "/**", "headers": [{"key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"}] }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/challenge{,/**}",
        "function": "preRender"
      },
      {
        "source": "/homa{,/**}",
        "function": "preRender"
      }
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem is that urls such as https://myproj-4324b.web.app/#/challenge don't trigger the `preRender` function.
I guess everything that comes after the '#' is ignored, but I'm not sure how to configure the rewrite by the prefix.
How can I make all the urls go through the `preRender` function?

Comment: Hi. Have you found a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can I know what is your `GCP resource location` in firebase project? If it is not in us-central1, below is the answer.

Based on the official docs from [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct-requests-to-function), there is a important note stated:

**Important: Firebase Hosting supports Cloud Functions in us-central1 only.**

So if your firebase project location is located in other region, the URL to access the `Firebase Functions` should be like this

> https://us-central1-yourProjectName.cloudfunctions.net/yourFunctionsName

I personally test with a new firebase project with locate to **us-central1**, its work by following this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct-requests-to-function), I able to connect my `Firebase Functions` using custom URL.